# Splitting string to list in Entity Framework

Tags: javascript, entity-framework

I have the following string :

DetailsParameters =  "Id=1,UserId=1,2,3"

In entity framework stored procedure I am trying to split the above string as :

```
"Id=1" and "UserId=1,2,3"
```

Currently, I have the following code which is splitting the above mentioned string at comma which is incorrect.

```
if (DetailsParameters != "")
                    {
                        List<Details> adlist = new List<Details>();
                        DetailsParameters.Split(',').ToList().ForEach(delegate (string s)
                        {
                            adlist.Add(new Details()
                            {
                                AlarmLogId = AlarmLogId,
                                ParameterKey = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('=')),
                                ParameterValue = s.Substring(s.IndexOf('=') + 1, (s.Length - (s.IndexOf('=') + 1)))
                            });
                        });

                        context.Details.AddRange(adlist);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to get too complicated about it, you could do something like this:

```
//var DetailsParameters = "Id=1,UserId=1,2,3";
//var DetailsParameters = "UserId=1,2,3,Id=1";
var indexOf = DetailsParameters.IndexOf("UserId=");
//if the index of "UserId=" is at the start, it should find the other word "Id=" to split
if (indexOf == 0) indexOf = DetailsParameters.IndexOf("Id=", "UserId=".Length);
var firstParameter = DetailsParameters.Substring(0, indexOf);
var secondParameter = DetailsParameters.Substring(indexOf, DetailsParameters.Length - firstParameter.Length);

var firstParameterValue = firstParameter.Split('=')[1].Split(new string[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var secondParameterValues = secondParameter.Split('=')[1].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: thanks this is working. But, the Details Parameters can be anything For example: Id=1,2,3,UserId=1" or Id=1,2,UserId=1,2. can you please help me with a generic code which will separate the Id and UserId values?

Comment: thanks.. so any type and number of parameters can be passed for example Id=1,3,6,UserId=1,2,3,Name=Sam,Harry etc from server.. can you please help make the code work for any kind of parameters passed?

Comment: I think it's better if you try something before trying to get an answer piece by piece. If you need help AFTER you tried something, we can help you :). Remember to accept the answer if it helped you :)